# Checking fields of a structure for empties then assigning them default values

Tags: matlab, struct

Below is an example what I would like to do.  Given two structure arrays, I want to search `test_value` structure to see if any fields are empty.  If a field is empty, I want to replace the empty with the corresponding value in the `default_value` structure.

```
test_values   = struct();
test_values.x = 2;
test_values.y = [1 0 4];
test_values.z = [];

default_values   = struct();
default_values.x = 0;
default_values.y = [1 1 1];
default_values.z = 2;

% Check if empty.  I want to check every field in the structure but too many 
% fields for this approach.
if isempty(test_values.z)
    test_values.z = default_values.z;
end
```

Does anyone know of better way then using `if` statements for each field?   I appreciate any help you may provide.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the fields using `fieldnames` and simply loop through

```
f = fieldnames( test_values );
for ii = 1:numel(f)
    if isempty( test_values.(f{ii}) )
        % Note the use of the .(___) notation to index a field with a string variable
        test_values.(f{ii}) = default_values.(f{ii});
    end
end
```

You could also use `isfield` to check the field has a default, before trying to apply it!